# R XML out of a database into a list

Tags: sql, r, xml

I'm trying to get a XML part out of my database into RStudio using R code.

The database is a Microsoft SQL. It looks like this:

```
    SELECT [url]
      ,[attributeID]
      ,[propertyQuality]
      ,[type]
      ,[valueOld]
      ,[valueNew]
      ,[utcTime]
      ,[meaning]
      ,[auditSecurityID]
      ,[auditUserActionID]
      ,[auditAlarmID]
      ,[description]
  FROM [EventLog].[dbo].[Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry]
  INNER JOIN AuditChange ON AuditChange.id=Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry.auditChangeID
  INNER JOIN UserLogEntry ON UserLogEntry.id=Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry.userLogEntryID
```

The value I want to extract is "valueNew", which looks something like this and is different from row to row:

```
<ResourceReference name="value"><ResourceId name="resourceIdVal">BatchReset</ResourceId><RevisionRef name="revision"><RevisionType name="revisionTypeVal">Specific</RevisionType><Revision name="revisionVal">1</Revision></RevisionRef></ResourceReference>

<FormatExternal name="value">BLANK</FormatExternal>
```

So in R I'm loading it in with:

```
auditChangeUserLog <- sqlQuery(con, "
                         SELECT [url]
                               ,[valueOld]
                               ,[valueNew]
                               ,[utcTime]
                               FROM [EventLog].[dbo].[Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry]
                               INNER JOIN AuditChange ON AuditChange.id=Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry.auditChangeID
                               INNER JOIN UserLogEntry ON UserLogEntry.id=Rel_AuditChange_UserLogEntry.userLogEntryID
                               ", stringsAsFactors=FALSE);

rm(con)
```

Then I try to get the XML into a list to add it back later behind the utcTime.

```
for(xml in 1:nrow(auditChangeUserLog))
{
  result[xml] <- list(xmlToDataFrame(auditChangeUserLog$valueNew[xml]))
}
```

With the second entry from the auditChangeUserLog I get the following error:

> ```
> Error in matrix(vals, length(nfields), byrow = TRUE) : 
> 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
> ```

If you need more information, please let me know.

Update 11.09.17:

With dput as suggested I get the following error:

```
"<ResourceReference name=\"value\"><ResourceId name=\"resourceIdVal\">BatchReset</ResourceId><RevisionRef name=\"revision\"><RevisionType name=\"revisionTypeVal\">Specific</RevisionType><Revision name=\"revisionVal\">1</Revision></RevisionRef></ResourceReference>"
"<FormatExternal name=\"value\">BLANK</FormatExternal>"
"<LotId name=\"value\">-</LotId>"
"<DateTimeUTCDelimited name=\"value\"><unsigned_short name=\"year\">0</unsigned_short><octet name=\"month\">0</octet><octet name=\"day\">0</octet><octet name=\"hour\">0</octet><octet name=\"minute\">0</octet><octet name=\"sec\">0</octet><unsigned_long name=\"microsec\">0<"
StartTag: invalid element name
Premature end of data in tag unsigned_long line 1
Premature end of data in tag DateTimeUTCDelimited line 1
Error: 1: StartTag: invalid element name
2: Premature end of data in tag unsigned_long line 1
3: Premature end of data in tag DateTimeUTCDelimited line 1
```

Update 11.09.17 (2)

I was playing around a little bit and now I have an other error:

The inpud is:

```
> print(auditChangeUserLog$valueNew[c(1:5)])
[1] "<AdjustmentValue name=\"value\"><AdjustmentState name=\"state\">Active</AdjustmentState><string name=\"value\">3,4</string></AdjustmentValue>" 
[2] "<AdjustmentValue name=\"value\"><AdjustmentState name=\"state\">Active</AdjustmentState><string name=\"value\">5,0</string></AdjustmentValue>" 
[3] "<AdjustmentValue name=\"value\"><AdjustmentState name=\"state\">Irrelevant</AdjustmentState><string name=\"value\"></string></AdjustmentValue>"
[4] "<AdjustmentValue name=\"value\"><AdjustmentState name=\"state\">Irrelevant</AdjustmentState><string name=\"value\"></string></AdjustmentValue>"
[5] "<AdjustmentValue name=\"value\"><AdjustmentState name=\"state\">Active</AdjustmentState><string name=\"value\">10</string></AdjustmentValue>"
```

I'm doing as I said before:

```
for(xml in 1:nrow(auditChangeUserLog))
{
  result[xml] <- list(xmlToDataFrame(auditChangeUserLog$valueNew[xml]))
}
```

And I get this error message:

```
Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xB5 0x6D 0x3C 0x2F
Error: 1: Input is not proper UTF-8, indicate encoding !
Bytes: 0xB5 0x6D 0x3C 0x2F
```

I think the biggest problem is that the XML code is from row to row a little bit different.

Comment: Welcome to SO. To increase chances of getting answers, you should provide a [reproducible example](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reprex/README.html#what-is-a-reprex) as asked by the R tag (hover over it). I.e. the minimal & for anyone runable code that reproduces the error msg. Adding `dput(auditChangeUserLog[1:2])` to your post might be helpful.

Comment: Hey @lukeA, thank you for your answer. With dput in the original code I get an other error (I add it aboth)